# what kind of file has the extension ".json.db"?

Tags: json, database, file

I came across a file that have the following extension ".json.db"
I can't find what kind of file is it.

Any ideas.
thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do the contents look like? Is it a binary file or text?

Comment: it is text and its format is Json

Answer (score 0):

This extension is used by many different databases, run the command `file my-file.json.db` to try to figure out which one created it.

[file](http://darwinsys.com/file/)  is "a file type guesser"

Comment: I got the following result:  "ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators"